# Trouble getting Ember Validations to work

Tags: validation, ember.js

Since Ember doesn't support form validation out of the box (as of this writing anyway), I am looking for a way to validate forms. I came across Dockyards [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) and the consensus seems to be that this is the goto module for form validation in EmberJS.

I'm trying to get it to work, but I'm having some trouble getting started.

I'm not using Ember CLI as referenced in the docs, so I have downloaded a compiled ember-validations.js from http://builds.dockyard.com/ and have included ember-validations.js in my apps js file.

The docs now say to pass the validations.mixin into a controller:

So I'm using:

```
App.MemberaddController = App.FamilyController.extend(EmberValidations.Mixin,{
    needs: ["family","notifications"],
    familyController: Em.computed.alias('controllers.family'),
    notifications: Em.computed.alias('controllers.notifications'),

    validations: {
        firstname: {
            presence: true,
            presence : {message: 'mag niet leeg zijn'}
        }
    },

    init: function() {
        this.set('familyController.pageTitle', "Gezinslid toevoegen");
    },

    <etc...>

}
```

However in the browser I'm seeing

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: EmberValidations is not defined
```

Looking at the ember-validations.js I can see the mixin file being referenced as Ember.Validations.Mixin.

So when I pass that to my controller, like

```
App.MemberaddController = App.FamilyController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin,{
```

I'm seeing:

```
Error while processing route: memberadd Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined
```

In the ember-validations.js file at the `_validate` function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First on the off chance this is a new project and you have the option to use ember-cli I recommend you do so, the community is moving in that direction.

That said I think your bug is in here

```
validations: {
    firstname: {
        presence: true, <-- uneeded
        presence <-- remove this space: {message: 'mag niet leeg zijn'}
    }
},
```

should look like this

```
validations: {
    firstname: {
        presence: {message: 'mag niet leeg zijn'}
    }
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately no... Even with commenting out the whole validations object, I'm still getting the same error: ```Error while processing route: memberadd Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined```

Comment: Also unfortunately I can't switch to the CLI for this project :(

Comment: I took a peek at the source code it looks like the null is caused when the validators are null.  I'm not 100% sure but not having any validators seems like it could cause this kind of a problem.  If you have just presence: true does it work?